# python windows interpret the values from for loop to cmd command

Tags: python, windows, robocopy

Here is a code

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

saveerr = sys.stderr 
fsock = open('error.log', 'w') 
sys.stderr = sys.stdout = fsock

D = {}

D['\\\\aucb-net-01\\d$'] = '\\\\nasaudc01\\remote_site_sync\\aucb-net-01'
D['\\\\aupw-file-01\\e$'] = '\\\\nasaudc01\\remote_site_sync\\aupw-file-01'

for k,v in sorted(D.items()):
    print (k,":",v) 
    cmd = 'robocopy {} {} /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1'.format(k,v)
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line)
```

i would like to, insert the value of "K" and "v" in cmd  after robocopy command  , so that with in the for loop it will  perform robocopy for all the  source and destination mentioned in dictionary  D = {}

i would also like that the script checks for failures in the robocopy  output logs in error.log file

```
         Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :      2575         0      2575         0         0         0
Files :      6039         0      6039         0         2         0
Bytes :   1.547 g         0   1.547 g         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:53   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:53

Ended : Tue Aug 30 04:32:48 2016
```

if two files have failed then the script should send a mail to some email address.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the values of `k` and `v` into the `cmd` string?

Comment: "Robocopy {} {} /E ...".format (k, v)

Comment: Yes Jameous, i want to insert the values of  k and v in the robocopy command

Comment: google "Python String Substitution"

Answer (score 0):

The way in Python to do it would be:

```
cmd = 'robocopy {} {} /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1'.format(k, v)
```

or, in Python 3.6:

```
cmd = f'robocopy {k} {v} /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1'
```

**However, this is wrong!** It will fail if `k` and `v` have spaces, and it can be a [security hazard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) (imagine if `k = '; rm -rf /;`). The right way to spawn subprocesses is with this:

```
cmd = ['robocopy', k, v, '/E', '/MIR', '/W:2', '/R:1']
```

Comment: this does not work   cmd = ['robocopy', k, v, '/E', '/MIR', '/W:2`, '/R:1`]

Comment: but this is working  cmd = 'robocopy {} {} /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1'.format(k,v)

Comment: @user1602531 How did it not work? What was the error message?

Comment: also i would like to have one more feature in this script, once the robocopy finishes for one  D item, then the code should  search the error log file  for any errors  in the failed section.

Comment: @user1602531 Sorry! I made a typo. I just updated the code. Could you try again?

Comment: i have made the script like this now.

Comment: from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

saveerr = sys.stderr 
fsock = open('error.log', 'w') 
sys.stderr = sys.stdout = fsock

D = {}

D['\\\\aucb-net-01\\d$'] = '\\\\nasaudc01\\remote_site_sync\\aucb-net-01'
D['\\\\aupw-file-01\\e$'] = '\\\\nasaudc01\\remote_site_sync\\aupw-file-01'


for k,v in sorted(D.items()):
 print (k,":",v) 
 cmd = 'robocopy {} {} /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1'.format(k,v)
 p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
 for line in p.stdout:
  print(line)

Comment: yes Kirby , its working. Many thanks to Both of you. Franc and Kirby and everyone who read my post. :)

Comment: @user1602531 If this answer worked for you, then you can hit the green check mark next to it! ;)